# Can Saadia be married?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I recently went to the Bannered Mare in Whiterun after learning that not only can
you cook with the ingredients given, but there was a cooking pot there. There I met
Saadia. No matter what I do, she won't accept my Amulet of Mara, even after I finished
her quest and let her live. Is she a marriable character in Skyrim?

Comment: I'm actually not sure what the answer to this is.  It seems like it might be *no* but I'm not entirely certain at this point.  Maybe a few more answers would help. :)

Comment: @RavenDreamer Perhaps someone could add the console commands to make her marriageable and so distinguish their answer from the others?

Comment: I knew there were console commands, but I wasn't sure the addfac would work because I had tried it before and it didn't; besides, something like that is bound to be buggy. So I wanted to go the natural way.

Comment: http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=2176 Marry and companion free by Gotika mod

Comment: Even if you do **In the Time of My Need** and sided with Saadia instead of the Alikr, she can't be marriable.

Answer (score 8):

## No

You can't marry [Saadia](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Saadia).

You can see a [full list of all NPC's you can marry](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage) on the UESP

Comment: Unless of course you are playing on PC: [Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage) Players can force the marriage dialog option to appear on NPCs by opening the console, targeting the desired NPC, and typing the command "addfac 19809 1". This could possibly cause issues with NPCs who were not originally intended to have this option.

Answer (score 6):

She's not marriable. You can view the full list of potential spouses [here.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage)

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately Saadia is not one of the [female NPCs you can marry.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage)

Answer (score 1):

I saw a picture on Skyrim nexus. The mod was Saadia-No Scar. I was looking at some pics and I saw in the Dialogue that it said,"I'd like us to move somewhere else". I think this means there might be a patch or a mod to where you could marry her